# Blender does not render particles

Tags: rendering, particles

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMYlcUvJipY) on how to make a super speed effect in Blender.
I went through half of the tutorial but got stuck now. When rendering just like in the tutorial (at 23:26), I don't see the particles- only the background.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gzQABJ5eY7evXyjERgPtgg0O1oEh6Asx) is the Blender file if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got strips in the Video Sequence Editor, so Blender will try to render them instead of the actual scene.

You can uncheck "Sequencer" in Render / Post processing.

A good practice would be to create a new Scene (or even a new .blend) to handle the video editing separately.